# Music database to run track data against

Tags: sql, database, database-connection, connection-string, gracenote

I'm writing an app that will let me manually edit my iTunes music library from outside of iTunes using a SQL-like syntax. I know how to edit the library, but I want to be able to run my track info against some kind of online database to get the right info. I found GraceNote, which seems to be the big name when it comes to music databases (iTunes actually uses it), but I'm not sure how to connect to their database. I registered into their developer program, but I'm not sure where to go from there. I just want to know where I can get a connection string and table info.

Comment: You want a connection string for Gracenote's database?  I highly doubt their API is just direct database access.  What have you tried with their API and in what way is it not working?  Have you tried other services' APIs?  Maybe something like Discogs would be pretty straightforward.  It appears to just be a REST API of album info.

Comment: I guess I really didn't know much about it. I don't have much experience with databases beyond having direct access, as in where I work. I guess I should have started by asking how I can get track info online period. I always assumed that people provided databases for public use in various areas. I guess it doesn't work that way?

Comment: Correct, direct database access would at the very least present a significant security risk to any online service.  Instead what normally happens is that the service exposes a controlled API to which developers can integrate.  A common standard in use today is a REST API, often responding with JSON or perhaps XML data.  The API's documentation should indicate what standards it uses and provide some examples for how to use it.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I looked and apparently they do have an SDK, and others have written unofficial APIs that can access their data. I know where to go from here. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't use GraceNote as they seem to have no or little quality control. Use something like MusicBrainz, Discogs or EchoNest instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Gracenote's Web API?

https://developer.gracenote.com/web-api

If you are creating an iOS or Android app, then you should use their Mobile Client SDK:

https://developer.gracenote.com/mobile-client